# Hibernate HQL exception with multiple INNER JOINs

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, named-query

I have 3 tables representing 3 entities like this :

**Service class :**

```
Service
----------
- Long id (primary key)
- Collection<commandeLine> commandeLines (many to many)
- Date billingDate;
```

**CommandLine class :**

```
CommandLine
--------------
- Long id (primary key)
- Command (many to one)
- Collection<Service> services (many to many)
```

**Command class :**

```
Command
-------------
- Long id (primary key)
- Date date
- Collection<CommandLine> commandLines (one to many)
```

Now I have a named query on `Service.java`, that will return all services that have a billing date > to the date of at least one of the commands they are attached to. So (I guess) I have to use 2 inner joins to use `CommandLine` class that has an actual link to the `Command` class.

What I did with NamedQueries is :

```
@NamedQuery(name = "ServiceDateQuery", query = "SELECT s FROM Service s "
        + "INNER JOIN Command c WITH c.date > s.billingDate "
        + "INNER JOIN s.commandLines cl WITH cl.command = c.id") })
```

I get an error :

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!
```

I guess it doesn't like the fact that I don't link to Command from another entity. But what can I do? if I put s.CommandLines first, I won't be able to perform the query either.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not WITH, but WHERE and at the end of the query,
join in jpa are resolved automatically from the class model:

```
SELECT s FROM Service s INNER JOIN s.comandelines cl INNER JOIN cl.comand c
WHERE c.date > s.billingDate
```